# rails rspec request @cookies and @set_cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec

I need to send a cookie in request to controller from a rspec.
I use request.cookies['remember_token'] = 'foo' to set required cookie, but somehow controller receives wrong value left from previous requests.

E.g. I set cookie and send put request in spec:

```
before do
  request.cookies['remember_token'] = 'foo'
  put 'update', calendar_id: cal.id, id: @day.id, comment: 'Test comment!'
end
```

*puts request.inspect* in controller shows the following:

```
@set_cookies={"remember_token"=>"bar"}, @cookies={"remember_token"=>"foo"}
```

It seems that @set_cookies={"remember_token"=>"bar"} is left from previous request that was made befor in the same spec. Whe I than access cookies['remember_token'] in controller, it returnes the value from @set_cookies, not @cookies.

What is @set_cookies and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: Still no answer... I think I decided not to use 'before' in that case.